# How to add character to EasyOcr model?

Tags: python, easyocr

I am building a solver for [KenKen](https://www.kenkenpuzzle.com/), and for recognizing characters I am using `easyocr`. While testing the model, I hit a roadblock; it struggles with the division symbol. I tried to use the following code using `easyocr==1.6.2`:

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
reader.readtext('1.png')
```

This was the image that was used as `1.png`:

[image]

The output I am getting is sometimes an equals sign (`=`) in certain cases (different image configs) or sometimes a plus symbol (`+`), which would be okay if not for the fact that the plus sign is also used in KenKen.

Comment: I thought of manually adding the division symbol to the library, but that did not work. I've settled to instead utilize the probabilities that are given when a string of text is predicted; if the probability is low and it is a `+` or `=`, it is likely going to be a division symbol.